# Would this be my null hypothesis for the test on OLS

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, econometrics

[image: Question]

I have this question here and for part b), I was wondering if my null hypothesis would be

B=0, where B is the coefficient on r5km and B<0 as the alternative hypothesis.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
When you retype the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag 
& read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've 
tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help 
you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.